# Other ways to say "military glory"

Tags: phrases, synonyms, military

It seems like there are only so many ways to describe a person's career in the military. We can say "military glory", "military prestige", "military reputation", but are there ways of describing this without using the word "military" over and over again?

I'm currently writing about the Roman world, where the military plays a huge role in a person's status. What are some other ways to refer to this idea of "military glory"?

Thanks!

Comment: Did this person have many glorious victories? Perhaps against the Gauls? You could list those victories. Just don't [overdo it](https://youtu.be/cFdgjYoBMIg).

Comment: Hey there! I'm specifically talking about Augustus, who at this point, actually doesn't have that much military glory. So I talk about how other prominent leaders of the past have attained a lot of glory before becoming politically relevant, whereas Augustus still needs to work on that. Do you have any tips for this case?

Comment: Talk about the many victories of his illustrious sponsor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When discussing military achievement words such as valor or gallantry would also work. Use words that help to reflect individual accomplishments such as bravery, ingenuity, tactical prowess, etc.

In many cases, once you have established that the individual you are referring is in the military, merely using prestige, glory or reputation without the word military would not confuse the reader.

Example, 'Legatus Cassius had proven his valor on the field countless times against the barbarian hordes.' 
'The Legion had never tasted defeat under the command of Florus.'
Neither example requires the word military to imply service.

More to the exact request, 'Augustus showed great promise. However, he was not proven in battle.'

Comment: Combat prowess, strategic or tactical brilliance. Florus apparently had tactical prowess.